# Gradle sync failes after updated to new AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I updated to:

[image]

I get the following error:
[image]

There is something wrong with gradle sync.
I tried all solutions found in stackoverflow, but nothing works.

I have the following settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Which version did you update from? I tried downgrading AGP and Gradle version to the ones you use in my of my dummy projects but ran into issues as well. Might be that versions that old are simply not supported.

Comment: I don't know. But which Gradle version do you use? Maybe I can just use the same settings as you and it will work.

Comment: AGP version 7.1.3 and Gradle version 7.2

Comment: That helped me much. Thanks a lot. You can answer as my combination is buggy and I will accept :-)

Answer (score 0):

That combination of AGP and Gradle versions are (apparently) not supported by AS Bumblebee (Patch 3).

Updating to latest versions (AGP version 7.1.3, Gradle version 7.2) solves the issue.